# Проблема связи клиент-серверного приложения через мобильный интернет

Tags: c#, сокет

Я создал для приложения на c# с использованием сокетов: 1-е на ПК Windows - сервер, 2-е на android смартфон - клиент. Два наипростейших приложения, примеров коих полно по первым же ссылкам в интернете.
Я пытаюсь подключить их в одной сети через один ройтер - всё работает. Подключаю ПК к одному роутеру, смартфон - к другому, все опять работает (использовал ip серверного роутера, подсмотренный в его настройках). Отключаю wifi на смартфоне и включаю мобильный интернет. Пытаюсь подключиться, и ...
Ничего не работает. Приложения не видят друг друга. Я выставил все разрешения в манифесте, в настройках приложения на android, но всё равно ничего не работает. Обдумав всё, я решил, что дело в скрытых блокировках android или мобильных операторов, которые магическим образом обходят WhatsApp, VK и т.д. В общем, прошу помощи и совета.

Comment: Это может быть что угодно, начиная от блокировки нестандарнтых портов оператором \ провайдером и заканчивая банальной недоступностью вашего приложения в интернете.

Comment: Какой порт подключения используете? Сервер по какому протоколу отвечает, просто RAW сокет, или к примеру HTTP? IP вдрес внешний у сервера на какие 2 числа начинается? Вы знаете, чем отличается "белый" IP от "серого"?

Comment: Наиболее вероятный ответ на ваш вопрос - купите у вашего провайдера услугу "Статический белый IP адрес".

Comment: На  80% уверен что не настроен фаервол виндовс

Comment: И возможно что адрес не белый. Какая первая цифра адреса роутера?

Comment: Порт 20000. Какая разница, какой ip у серверного роутера? Клиент работает через интернет при помощи любого wifi (другой wifi, а не тот же самый), но не работает через мобильный интернет. P.s. это точно не проблема внешних/внутренних/белых/серых ip

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что ваша сеть приватная (частная) и из интернета чтобы увидеть что либо нужно много чего, тонкая настройка маршрутизаторов, проброс портов (port forwarding, port mapping) или же настройка «Обратного соединения».